# storage server all nfs users on full 666 file permissions

Tags: nfs, storage, shared-disk

How can I setup a shared storage location on a storage server shared via CIFS and NFS and all files written by CIFS and all users via NFS to write files and folders with full read/write permissions (folders 777, files 666).

Reason: I use a Pydio server to manage files between my computer and a central storage.
But this central storage is also accessed directly over CIFS and NFS with other systems.
All files written via CIFS I can do a force user and file creation mask, so that is covverred.
But for NFS that is a different story.
The Pydio server has an NFS mount to this storage location.

```
Storage Location
/etc/exports:
/storage/internal   *(rw,sync,all_squash)

Pydio client mount:
<IP>:/storage/internal /mnt/VODSTOR nfs rw,intr,noexec,rsize=16384,wsize=16384 0 0
```

all files written by this Pydio server have 644 file permissions. How to alter the parameters of the NFS export/mount options to write with file permission 666 and for folders 777...? Because then all other users should be able to copy, delete, change these files no matter if the use samba or NFS...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is - you can't.  NFS permissions are handled by the client and file create permissions controlled by the user umask.

What you *might* be able to do (it depends on OS support) - if you're using NFSv4 - is use an ACL. See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs4_acl), specifically, the part about inheritance.